# When the user list is displayed, I want the background color of the row to be sky blue for my favorite users.Is there an efficient way to do this?

Tags: python, django

I have a question ~!

When the user list is displayed, I want the background color of the row to be sky blue for my favorite users.

However, it is too inefficient to run the loop again for each row when printing the user model.

Is there any good way to solve this?

In other words, how can I make the background color of my favorite user row change when displaying the user list?

Is there a good way to make the color of the rows of my favorite users different without doing too many queries?

If there is such a way

I would appreciate it if you let me know

thanks

Link

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/wm/userlist/byajax">User List</a>
```

below is related code

url

```
    path('userlist/byajax', views.user_list_for_memo_view.as_view(), name = 'user_list_for_memo'),
```

view

```
class user_list_for_memo_view(ListView):
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return ['wm/_user_list_for_memo.html']
        return ['wm/user_list_for_memo.html']

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        print("query : ", query)

        if query != None:
            object_list = User.objects.all().filter(Q(username__contains=query)).order_by('-profile__skill_note_reputation');
            return object_list
        else:
            print("user list 출력 확인 ===========================================================")
            object_list = User.objects.all().filter(profile__public="yes").order_by('-profile__skill_note_reputation');
            print("result : ", object_list)
            return object_list
```

template (C:\django_inflearn2\wm\templates\wm_user_list_for_memo.html)

```
{% load static %}


{% if object_list.exists %}
    {% for u in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{u.id}}</td>
            <td id=user_name_{{u.id}}>

                <a href="/accounts/user_profile_information_view/{{u.username}}">
                    {{u.username}}
                </a
            </td>
            {% if u.username == request.user.username %}
            <td style="background-color:#DFF3FA">
                <input type="text" class="shortcut_subject_input_{{u.id}} form-control" value="{{u.profile.subject_of_memo}}"><br>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm update_memo_subject_btn float-right" data-id={{u.id}}>수정</a>
            </td>
            {% else %}
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="shortcut_subject_input_{{u.id}} form-control" value="{{u.profile.subject_of_memo}}">
            </td>
            {% endif %}

            <td>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-dark move_to_user_btn btn-sm" id={{u.id}}>Id 선택</a>
            </td>
            <td>

                <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm copy_to_me_from_user_id_btn" data-id={{u.id}} id={{u.username}}>
                    copy_to_me
                    <span class="" id="loading_for_copy_{{u.id}}" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>

            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="plus_btn_for_user btn btn-outline-dark" data-author_id="{{u.id}}" data-my_id="{{request.user.id}}">
                    <img src="{% static 'icon/plus.png' %}" alt="">
                </button>
            </td>
            <td id="skill_note_point_{{u.id}}">
                {{ u.recommandationuseraboutskillnote_set.count }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <h4>no article</h4>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
```

related table

```
like table => 

class RecommandationUserAboutSkillNote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+")

user.profile table =>

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    shortcut_user_id = models.CharField(default="me", max_length=40)
    selected_category_id = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(TeamInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="member")
    subject_of_memo = models.CharField(max_length=60) 
    skill_note_reputation = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Did my answer below help you? If so please consider marking it correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an inline if statement in your template. Your templates is not that clear what row you want you want sky-blue so for the sake of clarity here is an example.

```
 <td style="background-color: {% if u.is_favorite %} sky-blue {% else %} not-sky-blue {% endif %}">
  ....
 </td>
```